# press enter to submit form

Tags: html, submit, enter

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Login</TITLE>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      <!--- PASSWORD PROTECTION SCRIPT
        function TheLogin() {

        var password = '123';

        if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
          top.location.href="correct.php";
        }
        else {
          location.href="incorrect.html";
          }
        }

        // End hiding --->
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      BODY { COLOR: #0000FF; FONT: 16px verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal }
    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </HEAD>
  <BODY bgColor="#FFFFFF">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <center>
      <p>please insert your password</p>
      <form name="login" id="formid" style="margin: 0px">
        <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="pass" id="passid" size="17" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;" style="width: 152px; margin: 5px;"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Click to Login" style="width : 150px; margin: 3px; left: 183px; top: 175px;" onClick="TheLogin(this.form)" >
      </form>
    </center>
    <br><br><br>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

How can I submit a form with just the Enter key on a text input field, with having submit button?

that i want protect some page that no one can access without password

it's working with button but with  "enter button" not working
so please any hep with change my code

Answer (score 0):

using jquery you can do it:

```js
$('#textbox').bind('keypress', function(e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    $('#button').click();
                }
            });
```

Comment: it dose not work brother
i did put your code in header
if you sure about it could u please put the full code

Comment: You should paste it at the end of code, before </body> tag.